# Does there exists a probability measure for a first category set to make it meaure zero?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I know that neither the class of first category sets or the class of measure zero sets include the other, but i have a question below. For a compact metric space X, is there a borel probability measure on X such that any subset A of first category in X is measure zero within this measure.

Comment: Yous should look at 'Measure and Category' by Oxtoby.

Comment: Thank you. I have roughly read oxtoby's book. I have seen that neither those two concepts imply the other, but for a certain first category set, i don't know does there exist a probability measure to make it measure zero

Comment: Are you seeking a Borel probability measure such that a particular specified $A$ of first category has measure zero, or a Borel probability measure such that *all* first category sets have measure zero?

Comment: Thank you. I'm seeking a Borel probability measure such that all first category sets have measure zero. For a particular specified A of first category has measure zero, may be i can take the dirac measure.

Comment: Thank you for your patient guidance, now i have correct the question, and sorry for the mistakes.

Comment: You seem to be looking for a so-called category measure. Oxtoby discusses one famous example in the last chapter. They’re pretty rare. They only exist on special algebras. Kunen has a nice example under CH of a compact L space that has a category  measure

Comment: Thank you very much! I have found the answer i need through your teaching.

Answer (score 1):

If $X$ is a finite set with the discrete metric, then the empty set is the only set of first category, so any probability measure on $X$ will satisfy your condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. If X is a general compact metric space,  does the probability measure exist?